# Native Support for Settings Profiles

Tags: settings, stock-android

Does anyone know if stock Android natively supports settings profiles, or if there is any plan to do so? To be clear, I am not talking about the user profiles feature that was introduced in Lollipop, but rather settings profiles that allow you toggle settings (e.g. WiFi on/off, GPS on/off, etc) in bulk based on a pre-defined set of profiles (Home, Work, Silent, etc.). I was first introduced to this feature via CyanogenMod, and loved it. I'm currently using a third-party app to achieve the same effect, but this seems like the sort of thing that should really be native to the OS itself. I've tried googling, but all I can find is information on the new users profile feature and third-party apps.

Comment: Are you pointing to the functionality to change quick settings?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. I'm aware of the quick settings menu that can be pulled down from the notifications bar at the top and used to quickly toggle settings individually. This is not what I'm asking about.

Comment: @Firelord the question isn't *where* to switch things, but rather *how to bulk-switch ***with a single tap***. Quick-settings would still involve toggling each feature separately. See the [CM Wiki on this](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/EndUser.Profiles), and check [these images](https://www.google.com/search?q=cyanogenmod+profiles&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch) to see what it's about :)